# Programmatic way of checking for Windows updates

Tags: go, com, windows-10, windows-update

I am writing a utility to automatically set up some things on a fresh install of Windows 10.  One of the things I'd like it to do is to automatically do the equivalent of clicking the "Check for updates" button in the Windows Update screen. I am writing the utility in Go.

Using the `ole` package I've tried creating a COM object from the class `Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate` and calling `DetectNow()` on that object.  But this seems to do nothing, so not sure if I'm doing something wrong with calling this method, or if there is some other way to check for updates.

Is there anyway to programmatically check for Windows updates using COM or some other means (doesn't have to be in Go)?

EDIT: here is how I call DetectNow:

```
unknown_object, err := oleutil.CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Could not create an AutoUpdate object: %v", err)
    error_and_exit()
}
iid_iautomaticupdates := ole.NewGUID("673425BF-C082-4C7C-BDFD-569464B8E0CE")
iautomaticupdates := unknown_object.MustQueryInterface(iid_iautomaticupdates)
defer iautomaticupdates.Release()
_, err = iautomaticupdates.CallMethod("DetectNow") //throw away return value since it is always nil
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Could not start Windows Updates: %v", err)
    error_and_exit()
}
```

Comment: This is the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/portal-client but I think it's the same as your Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate DetectNow (ie: you're already suing COM) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iautomaticupdates-detectnow

Comment: Thank you.  Yea, this is the same API I've been using.  I am calling DetectNow() and  it returns S_OK, but doesn't seem to do anything.  Not sure if there is any other call I am missing

Comment: DetectNow is like end-users' "check for updates" button. It's just a trigger and works asynchronous, won't return any specific (it will just save some time for when you search for updates next time). You can call the IAutomaticUpdates2::Results https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb513699(v=vs.85) if you need extra info. To detect what *are* the updates if any, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/searching--downloading--and-installing-updates

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to IAutomaticUpdates2::Results.  Unfortunately, it seems that DetectNow() does not affect LastSearchSuccesDate.  Even across multiple runs of my utility, this value does not change at all, which leads me to think that DetectNow() is doing nothing or failing silently.  Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: A good thing is that LastSearchSuccessDate does match with the date in the Windows Update screen, so that's at least a reliable value.

Comment: I have updated my post with how I call DetectNow

Comment: The way you call it will not change anything, it's just more complex. Use the link I gave, there's no other way to search for update than use the UpdateSearcher.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's just more complex"?  Should have been more clear: by supplying the code, I wondering if there is anything im missing in my code.  Are you saying that my code should be equivalent for clicking "Check for updates"?

But one thing it also seems is that clicking the "Check for updates" button actually changes the LastSearchSuccessDate.  Calling DetectNow() does not. So they don't seem to be equivalent in functionality even though it should be?